# Joining multiple MySQL Tables with one relations ID

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have 4 MySQL tables on identity column is in common between all these tables, 
Tables in Sequence:
1- Items.
2- Sales.
3- Puchases.
4- Returned.

ItemID appears in all of these tables, WHEN i use LEFT JOIN i get duplicates like:

```
    select 
    a.ItemID AS ItemID,
    a.Item_title AS ItemTitle,
    SUM(b.qty) AS SoldQty,
    SUM(c.qty) AS PurQty,
    SUM(d.qty) AS RetQty
from items a 
left join sales b on a.ItemID = b.items_ItemID
left join purchases c on a.ItemID = c.items_itemID
left join returned d on a.ItemID = d.items_ItemID
group by a.ItemID
```

That query was one of the many tries that i've tried :D the result i get is always unique for sales but duplicates for other tables ..

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want the total number of sales, purchases, returned etc per item id from a.  If that's the case, try thinking about an easier piece of the problem first: how do I get the sum of each sales quantity, grouped by item id?

To do that you'd do something like:

```
select b.items_ItemID, sum(b.qty) as total_sales_qty 
from sales b group by b.items_ItemID
```

You could do the same thing for tables c and d.

Once you've got those, you can join them all together like this:

```
select a.ItemID, bb.total_sales_qty, cc.total_purchases_qty, dd.total_returned_qty 
from items a 
left join (
    select b.items_ItemID, sum(b.qty) as total_sales_qty 
    from sales b group by b.items_ItemID) bb 
on a.ItemID = bb.items_ItemID 
left join (
    select c... etc) cc
on a.ItemID = cc.items_ItemID
... etc
```

Comment: actually that didnt work for me, my query was a sample, i need more than sum of qty but i gave that example to refer that i have aggregate functions beside the normal columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use MySQL, but in SQL Server, you could use the `distinct` directive, so duplicate rows appear as just a single row. All the returned columns must be identical, mind you.

```
Select Distinct a.ItemID AS ItemID,... From....
```

Hope this helps